# My Apple Script Editor code doesn't work gives "Syntax Error Expected end of line but found identifier."

Tags: applescript, error

I insert this code:

```
tell application "Notes"
  set theMessages to every note
  repeat with thisMessage in theMessages
    set myTitle to the name of thisMessage
    set myText to the body of thisMessage
    set myCreateDate to the creation date of thisMessage
    set myModDate to the modification date of thisMessage
    tell application "Evernote"
      set myNote to create note1 with text myTitle title myTitle notebook "Imported Notes" tags ["imported_from_notes"]
      set the HTML content of myNote to myText
      set the creation date of myNote to myCreateDate
      set the modification date of myNote to myModDate
    end tell
  end repeat 
end tell
```

And it gives me the error: Syntax Error Expected end of line but found identifier.

Any idea what the problem with the code is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the version of **Evernote** I tried is not **AppleScript** *scriptable*.

When trying to add **Evernote** to the **Library** in **Script Editor**, in order to review its **AppleScript** *dictionary*, it errs with: **Add Item Unable to add the item because it is not scriptable.**

Additionally, when running the following *command* in **Script Editor**:

```
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    get has scripting terminology of application process "Evernote"
```

Its result is: ***false***

---

Apparently at one time **Evernote** was **AppleScript** *scriptable*, however, in **macOS Catalina**, testing with **Evernote** from https://evernote.com/download/ and checking **Evernote** > **About Evernote** it shows:

> 10.11.5-mac-ddl-public (2530)
> Editor: v121.2.15734
> Service: v1.32.4
> © 2019 - 2021 Evernote Corporation. All rights reserved

Looking for the typical **AppleScript** *dictionary* in `/Applications/Evernote.app/Contents/Resources/` there is no **Evernote.sdef** *file* as would be expected if it was fully **AppleScript** *scriptable*.

---

If you do have a version of **Evernote** that is **AppleScript** *scriptable* then try the following, which I cannot test under the circumstances:

Change `note1` to `note` in:

```
set myNote to create note1 with text myTitle title myTitle notebook "Imported Notes" tags ["imported_from_notes"]
```

You might also want to put in some *parentheses*. e.g.

```
set myNote to (create note with text myTitle title myTitle notebook "Imported Notes" tags ["imported_from_notes"])
```

Unfortunately without a version of **Evernote** that is **AppleScript** *scriptable*, I cannot offer more.

Comment: I have "Evernote Legacy"... not sure how it go there, but it works on Catalina and beyond and it responds correctly. However... it's another app, which is lame.